# Javascript while loop variable

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused as to why `myCounter = myCounter + 1;` does not require a `var` to be declared before the statement itself.

```
var myCounter=0;
var lineBreak='<br>';

while (myCounter <= 5) {
    document.write('Hello World' + lineBreak);
    myCounter = myCounter + 1;
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem here...??

Comment: Because variable is only declared once.

Comment: You should look into scope and research the difference between a global and local variable in javascript to really understand the answer to this question.

Comment: if you define it within loop you cannot use it in next iteration

Comment: My apologies for asking such a dumb question.  I started learning javascript less than 16 hours ago.  We all have to start somewhere. Just trying to make sense of it all.

Comment: I'm also confused, what actually your problem. It seems ok.

Comment: There is no issue with the code.  I just wanted to understand why no var was needed in order for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is initialized on the first line.

```
var myCounter=0;
```

This same variable is used the other two lines that reference it

```
while (myCounter <= 5) {
    document.write('Hello World' + lineBreak);
    myCounter = myCounter + 1;
}
```

If it was not initialized at the top (missing `var` keyword) then it would considered a 'global' variable. This is bad practice of course and you should always define your variables in only the scope that you need them in. You can even [put a `"use strict";` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) at the top of your file to throw exceptions when variables aren't defined.